# vectorized table operations in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Based on given averages and standard deviations, I'm trying to fill columns with various sample runs. What I have right now is:

```
A = data.table(ave = c(20, 3), std = c(.1, 1))
A[, paste0("scenario", c(1:3)) := rnorm(2, ave, std)]
```

Which results in the table:

```
ave  std scenario1 scenario2 scenario3
 20  0.1   20.2377   20.2377   20.2377
  3  1.0    2.6497    2.6497    2.6497
```

So clearly, its running rnorm on one vector, then repeating that same vector for each column. How do I make it recalculate each column? I've tried things like

```
matrix(rnorm(6, ave, std), 2, 3)
```

or using `transpose(lapply(...))` but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `rnorm` for each column:

```
A[, paste0("scenario", c(1:3)) := lapply(1:3, function(x) rnorm(2, ave, std))]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `replicate`

```
A[, paste0("scenario",c(1:3)) := replicate(3, rnorm(2, ave, std), simplify = FALSE)]
```